# creating users on TFS 2010

Tags: windows-7, user-management, team-foundation-server, web

I want to create a user for my local TFS server.
The server is installed on a Win7 64 bit system.
Is it possible to create a user which logins using the TFS' authentication?

To be clearer, Can I create a user which is not part of Windows domain?
I dont want to create a separate user on the Win7 machine for a separate TFS user.

e.g. The perfect example of this is SQL Server which provides windows based and SQL Server authentication.
Is there any non-Windows based authentication available with TFS, if so how can i use it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think this is possible (TFS is not SQL Server): all TFS users are either domain or local Windows users.

(With local users, if a local user exists on another computer with the same name *and password* then that local user can also logon automatically as with Windows file and printer sharing.)

Comment: Well, I know its not SQL server, but wanted to know if there is a possibility of doing something similar. :)

Comment: @manishKungwani: I assumed that, but SQL Server providers a useful and well known contrast.